# In ruby, how to rename a text file, keep same handle and delete the old file

Tags: ruby, handle, delete-file

I am using a constant (FLOG) as a handle to write to my log. At a given point, I have to use a temporary log, and later append that content to the regular log, all that with the same handle, which is used through a bunch of methods.
My test program is below.  After closing the handle 'FLOG' associated with the temp log, when I re-assign FLOG to the new log, this somehow re-opens the temp log, and I can't delete it.
Is there a way to make sure that the old temp file stays close (so I can delete it)

```
# Pre-existing log:
final_log = "final_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt"

#Writing something in it
File.open(final_log, "w+") { |file| file.write("This is the final log: #{final_log}\n") }

# temp log:
temp_log = "temp_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt"
FLOG = File.new(temp_log, "w+")

# write some stuff in temp_log
FLOG.puts "Writing in temp_log named #{temp_log}"

# closing handle for temp_log
FLOG.close  

# avoid constant reuse warning:
Object.send(:remove_const,'FLOG') if Object.const_defined?('FLOG')

# need to append temp_log content to final_log with handle FLOG 
FLOG = File.open(final_log, "a+") 

# appending old temp log to new log 
File.open(temp_log, "r").readlines.each do |line|
    puts "appending...  #{line}"
    FLOG.puts "appending...  #{line}"               
end

# closing handle    
FLOG.close

# this tells me that 'temp_log' is somehow re-opened:
ObjectSpace.each_object(File) { |f| puts("3: #{temp_log} is open") if f.path == temp_log && !f.closed? }

File.delete(temp_log)       # Cant do that:
# test_file2.rb:35:in `delete': Permission denied - temp_20150324.txt (Errno::EACCES)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to use a temp file, use [`tempfile`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html)

```
require 'tempfile'

# Pre-existing log:
final_log = "final_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d")}.txt"

#Writing something in it
File.open(final_log, "w+") { |file| file.write("This is the final log: #{final_log}\n") }

# give the tempfile a meaningful prefix
temp_log = Tempfile.new('foobar')
begin
  $flog = temp_log

  # write some stuff in temp_log
  $flog.puts "Writing in temp_log named #{temp_log.path}"

  # need to append temp_log content to final_log with handle $flog
  $flog = File.open(final_log, "a+")

  # reopen temp_log for reading, append to new log
  temp_log.open.readlines.each do |line|
    puts "appending...  #{line}"
      $flog.puts "appending...  #{line}"
  end

  # closing handle
  $flog.close
ensure
  # delete temp_log
  temp_log.unlink
end
```

And while globals are generally bad, hacking a constant so that you can use it like a global is worse.

Comment: So I did something bad and really made it worse!  Thanks a lot for that practical solution.  I realized I jumped too quickly to a solution without learning enough about it.  Still so much to learn.

Answer (score 0):

`temp_log` is still open because you didn't close it. If you did something like:

```
temp_log_lines = File.open(temp_log, 'r') { |f| f.readlines }
```

then the I/O stream for to `temp_log` would be closed at the end of the block. However, doing `File.open(temp_log, "r").readlines` takes the `IO` object returned by `File.open` and calls `readlines` on it, which you then call `each` on with an accompanying block. Since the block is part of your call to `each` and not `File.open`, the stream is not closed at the end of it, and stays open for the rest of the program.

As to why you can't delete `temp_log` at the end of the program, it's hard to say without knowing what's going on in the underlying file system. Neither Ruby nor the underlying (POSIX) OS will complain if you delete a file that you've opened a stream for and not closed; the file will be unlinked but the stream will persist and still have the contents of the file and so on. The error you're getting is saying that the owner of the Ruby process for this program doesn't have the rights to delete the file the program created. That's strange, but hard to diagnose just from this code. Consider the directory the program is working in, what the permissions on it are, etc.

Speaking more generally, there are some things you could make use of in Ruby here that would make your life easier.

If you want a temporary file, there is a [Tempfile](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0.preview1/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) class you could make use of that does a lot of legwork for you.

The idiomatic way of doing I/O with files in Ruby is to pass a block into `File.open`. The block is handed an I/O stream for the file that is automatically closed at the end of the block, so you don't need to do it manually. Here's an example:

```
flog = File.new(temp_log, 'w+') do |f|
  f.puts "Writing in temp_log named #{temp_log}"
end
```

`FLOG` is not a true constant in your code. [A constant is only a constant if its value never changes throughout the life of the program it's declared in.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_%28computer_programming%29) Ruby is a very permissive language, so it allows you to reassign them, but warns you if you do. Stricter languages would throw an error if you did that. `FLOG` is just a normal variable and should be written `flog`. A good use for a constant is a value external to the action of your program that your program needs be able to reference—for instance, instead of writing `3.141592653589793` every time you need to refer to an approximation of pi, you could declare `PI = 3.141592653589793` and use `PI` afterwards. In Ruby, this has been done for you in the `Math` module—`Math::PI` returns this. User settings are another place constants often show up—they're determined before the program gets going, help to determine what it does, and should be unmodified during its execution, so storing them in constants sometimes makes sense.

You describe the program you supplied as a test program. Ruby has really great testing libraries you could make use of that will be nicer than writing scripts like this. Minitest is part of the Ruby standard library and is my favorite testing framework in Ruby, but a lot of people like RSpec too. (I'd like to link to the documentation for those frameworks, but I don't have enough reputation—sorry. You'll have to Google.)

It'll be hard to make use of those frameworks if you write your code imperatively like this, though. Ruby is a very object-oriented language and you'll get a lot out of structuring your code in an object-oriented style when working in it. If you're not familiar with OO design, some books that have been really good for me are *Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby* by Sandi Metz, *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by Martin Fowler et al., and *Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests*, by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce. (Same thing here with the lack of links.)

Comment: I understand my use of a 'constant' as a handle was poor practice. But I was puzzled by the fact that after closing the temp_log handle (FLOG.close), the file remained close until I re-use the handle for another file.  I guess it comes from my trying to make a constant 'unconstant'. In any case, thank you so much for the additional pointers about testing and for the book references.  I am actually trying to learn more about writing code in the real object-oriented way.

Comment: It actually doesn't come from changing the value of FLOG—like I said above, you later re-open a stream to temp_file and when you do that you never close it again. Both times that you assign a stream to FLOG you do close it. See line 24 in your code and what I say about it above.

Sure thing about the references! [Metz's book](http://www.poodr.com/) is a good one to start with.

By the way, if you feel that my answer or Max's has satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking one of them accepted. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work